# Filtering order in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I'm interested to filter table by django orm in specific order. Basically, it's simple search by two fields - name and description. I want to sort the result first by the "name" field concurrencies, and then by the "description" field concurrencies. Here is the example of raw sql:

`WITH checkpoints AS (SELECT *
                     FROM checkpoints_view
                     WHERE ...)
SELECT *
FROM checkpoints
WHERE name ILIKE '%KEYWORD%'
UNION ALL SELECT *
          FROM checkpoints
          WHERE description ILIKE '%KEYWORD%' AND name NOT ILIKE '%KEYWORD%';`

How can i generate sql like this in the django orm?

Thanks to all

P.S.: sorry for my english if i wasn't correct, i'm from not english-speaking country

```
class Checkpoint(models.Model, ReadOnlyModel):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Наименование')
    code_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Код остановки")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Описание")
    coordinate = models.PointField(verbose_name="Координата")
    routes = ArrayField(models.IntegerField())
    dates = ArrayField(models.DateField()) 

    class Meta: 
        db_table = 'checkpoints_view' 
        managed = False
```

Almost all of you right, but i want to result was ordered at start by rows, which passes filter of name field, and then, after all this - rows, which passed filter of description field

Comment: please share your model

Answer (score 2):

I think your code can be written without CTEs:

```
Checkpoint.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains='keyword') |
    (~Q(name__icontains='keyword') & Q(description__icontains='keyword')))
```

Comment: what is you problem?? why do you downvote only my answer?? what have i done to you ?? someone else has given the same answer but specifically you downvote my answer?

Comment: @Exprator you're here for reaping easy SO reputation. The other solution that you mention will return correct result although it is not an optimal solution. Your solution doesn't solve the problem - if you think or try, you'll see that it will give different results from the query posted in the question. There's nothing personal, I saw an incorrect answer and downvoted it.

Comment: saying 'not an optimal solution' made me think cause I always use my solution (I think it's more readable and didn't know it might be less efficient) so tried both solutions (mine and yours) on a simple django model  with a very simple query `(pk>10) or (pk < 10 and pk !=3)` and checked django sql query using `print(q.query)` they both generated same sql query.

Comment: I'm not sure about complex queries, maybe it's different for complex queries

Comment: @aliva better install `django-extensions` package and use `./manage.py debugsqlshell`, it's more convenient and will print all queries to the console. I was wrong when I said that your solution is not optimal - I checked and it seems that Django also generates optimal SQL query in your case.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the Django ORM does not use CTEs in the queries that it generates. That's because they have different behaviours across different RDBMS and not supported at all in mysql and sqlite.

So if you want to use a CTE in your query your only option is a [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries). Something like

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.raw('WITH checkpoints AS (SEL ....')
```

Comment: this is the problem, it's already working now on raw sql, but i want to implement this in django orm way

Thanks for the answer

Comment: btw i don't mean using "WITH " keyword strictly, it can be just two selects with union.

Comment: You asked a question, which we answered. What you had in mind we cannot answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
results = Checkpoint.objects.filter(
    name__icontains='str_1',
) | Checkpoint.objects.filter(
    description__icontains='str_2',
).exclude(
    name__icontains='str_3',
)
```